# cannot update state in .then() (redux toolkit)

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

**authSlice.ts**

```
getUser(state) {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/users/user/' + localStorage.getItem('token'))
        .then(res => {
            state.user = res.data // <--------- doesn't work
        })

        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })

    state.user = 1 // <--------- works
}
```

When I try to set the user in the .then() I get a revoked proxy error, but when I set it outside it works, I have a general idea as to why this is not working but I don't know how to make it work, any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should use `createAsyncThunk` for that and handle the state logic in the `extraReducer` slice object. https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk

Comment: You are never allowed to modify Redux state outside of a reducer. Please read up on the official Redux tutorial which also handles data fetching approaches: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Answer (score 0):

The promise/proxy should get revoked in catch() when the promise fails and not in the then() function.
There must be something wrong with your .then() call or something must be revoking the proxy at the start of the promise.